# How do I reference a reactive value in shiny without being dependent on it?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to reference a reactive value without necessarily refreshing every time it changes.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the isolate() function for that. Cheers.